# SQL query for the given select operation

Tags: sql, db2

Consider a table T, with columns

1. ID = e.g Customer ID
2. Expense = amount spent on buying an item
3. Date    =  Date of transaction
4. Item    = item bought

I want to perform following select operation on  T.

I want to find for each ID, the most expensive item that was bought on an earliest date.

For example if the table had three records like as follows

```
ID   Expense   Date         item
1    1000      10/20/2015   A
1    1000      10/21/2015   B
1    200       10/15/2015   C
```

It should pick the first row.

I wrote something like the following but it does not seem to work

```
select T.id. T.expense, T.date, T.item
from T inner join 
(select id, max(expense), min(date) from T
 group by id) w on T.id = w.id and T.expense=w.expense and T.date=w.date;
```

Please give some suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: SELECT MAX(Expense) GROUP BY ID ?

Comment: this `max(expense), min(date)` does not work the way you think it does.  there is no relationship between the expense and date fields here except they both occur with records of the same id.

Comment: This is easy on most any DB platform other than mysql, because the best solution will use Windowing functions which are not supported in MySql even though they've been part of the sql standard for more than 10 years.

Comment: @Hogan Other than that I am not sure what else to do. May be try another subquery and take min(date) there. I was hoping for a better solution than that.

Comment: @Joordan thanks for the reply but this wont select the field item that I eventually want as an output of my select.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @user123884 yes exactly -- with mysql I believe you need 2 or 3 sub-queries to get the results you want since mysql does not support windowing functions.

Comment: @Joel Sorry that was a mistake I am not using MySQL. The DB platform is oracle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry again, I was confused It is IBM DB2.

Comment: well, this is another thing now.

Comment: Suggestion: Use [Loops/PLSQL](http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-iterative-statements.htm) and some [conditional-checks](http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-conditional-statements.htm) in Oracle. Your work will be done. @user123884

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
    Select * from 
    (select row_number() over (partition by ID order by Expense desc, date asc)
    RN,  id, expense, date, item
    from T)T
    where RN=1
```

Comment: thanks for a quick reply but what about the records where max(expense) is the same. I am breaking the ties by picking the earliest date. See the example there.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This answer is wrong, because the question was originally tagged wrong. I'd edit, but there is already another correct answer here. I'm leaving this here because it still demonstrates a viable solution that even works on MySql, but you should really vote for the `row_number()` solution.

---

Think of doing this in three steps. First you need to find out what the max expense will be. Then you need to find the corresponding min date. Finally, you can get the whole record that matches those values. If it's possible to have multiple records for an ID that match both the max and the min, you'll need an additional step to get this down to a single record.

Each of these steps can be accomplished via a JOIN on a subquery:

```
select .*
FROM T tf --final
INNER JOIN (
    select Td.ID, Td.expense, MIN(Td.date) MinDate
    from T td --date
    INNER JOIN (
        select ID, MAX(expense) MaxExpense
        from T te --expense
       GROUP BY ID
    ) e on td.ID = e.ID AND td.expense = e.MaxExpense
    GROUP BY ID, expense
) d ON tf.ID = d.ID AND tf.expense = d.expense AND tf.date = d.MinDate
```

Again, this is much simpler with a DB engine that supports Window functions or the APPLY operator. Here's an APPLY example you could write with Sql Server:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM T t1
CROSS APPLY ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM T t2
    WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
    ORDER BY t2.expense DESC, t1.Date
) a
```

This feature is supported by Sql Server, Oracle, and Postgresql, and has been part of the ansi standard for more than 10 years now, and it's just one reason among several the MySql is quickly becoming a joke among anyone who has actually worked with more than one kind of database.

Comment: Don't you think windowing functions are clearer than APPLY?

Comment: Probably, but it's moot, as he's using MySql, which can't do either. This is just the solution that occurred to me first, and it's enough to prove that it would be easier using a different db. ... not that I expect him to switch in the middle of a project, but maybe next time he'll keep that in mind, or someone else will see it, and enough complaining like this might eventually get the MySql devs off their rear ends.

Comment: Hmm... I'd swear the question was originally tagged "MySql". It shows as oracle now, and I have meeting in 5 minutes so there's not time to edit the answer :(

Comment: It did show mysql originally -- that is why I posted the comments I did.  you can see him in the comments changing his mind.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle, DB2 or MS SQL you would do this to get the item on each row:

```
select T.id. T.expense, T.date, T.item,
       max(T.expense) OVER (partition by T.id order by T.date asc) as m_expense
from T
```

And this to get the items that match these criteria

```
SELECT id, expense, date, item
FROM (
  select T.id, T.expense, T.date, T.item,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by T.id order by T.expense DESC, T.date asc) as rn
  from T 
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

This makes use of one of a windowing functions.  The best way to explain what windowing functions is to say that they do exactly what you need:  Apply an function to a subset of rows (the window).

Comment: Does the order by have any meaning with max()?

Comment: Did you just stole my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select t.id, t.expense, min(t.date), t.item
from (select max(expense) as expense, id from T group by id) x
join t
    on t.id = x.id and t.expense = x.expense
group by t.id
```